# Javascript - scroll effect interferes with links

Tags: javascript, scroll, hyperlink, anchor

```js
$('body a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var goTo = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
  $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop:$('a[name="'+goTo+'"]').offset().top
  },1100);
  
  window.location.hash = "#"+goTo;
  
 });
```

There's my javascript code, which works fine, except when I try to click on links I get this error:

TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

this is because of e.preventDefault();
it prevents links to work, and you set it to all a tags in the body

try using another script

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1100);
            return false;
        }
    } 
});
```